# include_role combined with_items for role name

Tags: ansible

I want to selectively execute roles based on a list of roles passed to the play book.  However, this fails

```
- name: create container definitions for selected services
  include_role:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ selected_service_list }}"
```

with

`ERROR! 'item' is undefined`

I gather it is impossible to use a list of role names to control when we execute roles. Let me know if you know how to do this

Comment: The code should work as-is. In fact, there is an [example on ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#examples) showing the use case. It's also better to rename the loop var from `item` to else in case there are loops within the included roles.

Comment: @moon alas it does not work in ansible 2.3

Comment: That would explain. Seem to be a recent 2.8 changes.

Comment: Thanks, so It's definitely time to upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ansible latest 2020-07 one can follow this ([example from ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#examples))

For ansible 2.3 one should upgrade or can use this approach

```
- { role: myservice, when: "'myservice' in  selected_service_list" }
```